# Spring Data JPA Specification using CriteriaBuilder with a MANY TO MANY relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring data JPA.

I have two entities is Product and Category. They have many to many relationship.

I'm using @ManytoMany Annotation to define. And here is the details:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer productId;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
   
}

@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer categoryId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    )
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>(); 

}
```

Here is the Repository:

```
public interface ProductRepo extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {

    List<Product> searchProduct(Specification<Product> spec);
}
```

Now, I have a list of categoryId, I wanna get product in that categories.

```
public static Specification<Product> searchProductInCategory(List<Integer> categoryIdList) {
// how to build Specification?
}
```

How can I do that? Please help me implement and give me some way..
Thank you so much!